# Run php function in button OnClick (not submit)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I wanna run following query on function DeleteCus by clicking on a button.I tried following code for that.bt it is not working.

getting http://localhost/AdminLTE-2.1.1/CusRegReport.php?id=134 url after running notification.php
getting error  Undefined index: id in lin 67

```
<button type="button"  id = "button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" onclick ="window.location.href = href='PHP/notification.php?hello=true'">

<?php


 if (isset($_GET['hello'])) {
DeleteCus();


}

session_start();
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','dashboard') or die(mysqli_connect_error(''));

function notification(){
    global $dbc;
    $query = "SELECT `customer_id`, `customer_name` FROM `customer` WHERE `confirmation`IS NULL LIMIT 0, 30 ";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);        
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<a href='CusRegReport.php?id=" . $row['customer_id'] . "'><i class='fa fa-users text-red'>&nbsp;&nbsp;" . $row['customer_name'] . "&nbsp;&nbsp; needs to register</i></a>";        
     $_SESSION["count"] =mysqli_num_rows($result);  

    }

}

function RegReport(){
    global $dbc; 



    $id = $_GET['id'];  

   // $id = $mysqli->real_escape_string ($id);   

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `customer` WHERE `customer_id` = '$id'";
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc,$sql);
    while($line=mysqli_fetch_array($r))
    {
        $a= "<br/>" . $line['customer_name'] . "<br/>" . $line['ad_line_one'] .$line['ad_line_two'] .$line['ad_line_three'] .$line['web'] .$line['pub_pvt'] .$line['reg_no'] .$line['tax_no'] .$line['description'] .$line['attachments'] .$line['contact_name'] .$line['contact_salutation'] .$line['contact_designation'] .$line['contact_email'] .$line['contact_tp1'] .$line['contact_tp2'] .$line['md_fname'] .$line['md_lname'] .$line['md_email'] .$line['date']. "</a>";  

    }
}
function DeleteCus(){
global $dbc;   
$id =  $_GET['id'];
$sql = "DELETE FROM `customer` WHERE `customer`.`customer_id` = '$id'";
  $r = mysqli_query($dbc,$sql); 
}

?>
```

Comment: onclick ="window.location.href ='PHP/notification.php?hello=true'" >

Comment: You have an extra "= href" in your code. Remove that.

Comment: where do you print `$a` variable?

Comment: I corrected that one.but um getting error Undefined index: id in lin 67 (line 67 is in the function DleteCus $id=$_GET['id'];)
how can i directly call the php function without changing the URL.I think the error occurs because of the URL changing to "http://localhost/AdminLTE-2.1.1/PHP/notification.php?hello=true" when running the code

Answer (score 2):

Please replace the button code with the following code :

```
<button type="button"  id = "button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" onclick ="window.location.href='PHP/notification.php?hello=true'" />
```

Comment: actually I tried this.but um getting error Undefined index: id in lin 67 (line 67 is in the function DleteCus $id=$_GET['id'];

Answer (score 1):

TRY this code for button

```
<button type="button"  id = "button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" onclick ="window.location.href ='PHP/notification.php?hello=true'">
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<button type="button"  id = "button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" 
onclick="javascript:window.location.href='www.exampe.com/PHP/notification.php?hello=true&id=<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>'; return false;" >
```

also in your function

```
function DeleteCus($dbc,$id){
 $dbc=$dbc; 
if(isset['$_GET['id'])){  
$id =  $_GET['id'];
$sql = "DELETE FROM `customer` WHERE `customer`.`customer_id` = '$id'";
  $r = mysqli_query($dbc,$sql); 
}
}
```

when you are calling your function change it

```
if (isset($_GET['hello'])) {
DeleteCus($dbc,$id);


}
```

Comment: -I tried this one also.but um getting error Undefined index: id in lin 67 (line 67 is in the function DleteCus $id=$_GET['id'];) how can i directly call the php function without changing the URL.I think the error occurs because of the URL changing to "localhost/AdminLTE-2.1.1/PHP/notification.php?hello=true"; when running the code – IsharaRA

Comment: Thanks,its working,But error occured.


      $r = mysqli_query($dbc,$sql); // line 68
    
}

it'saying Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\wamp\www\AdminLTE-2.1.1\PHP\notification.php on line 68

Comment: please  comment result of   echo $sql = "DELETE FROM `customer` WHERE `customer`.`customer_id` = '$id'";

Comment: tried & no errors occur.bt nothing happens in my database.since the query is perfectly running on phpmyadmin it has no error.is there any problem with my code?

Answer (score 1):

remove extra href from button onclick event  window.location.href ='PHP/notification.php?hello=true

try this:-

Answer (score 1):

You have `$id =  $_GET['id'];` in method DeleteCus, but you didn't pass that parameter in your link in the button PHP/notification.php?hello=true. So, it should be `<button type="button"  id = "button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" onclick ="window.location.href ='PHP/notification.php?hello=true&id=XXX'">`. That's why it returns undefined index id in calling PHP method